# An IMO $1971$ longlisted problem

Tags: contest-math, recreational-mathematics

I have been stuck on this beautiful problem for a long time, but I have no idea as to where to start. The problem is as follows:

One Martian, one Venusian and one Human reside on Pluto. One day they make the following conversation:

*Martian*: I have spent $1/12$ of my life in Pluto.
*Human*: I also have.
*Venusian*: Me too.
*Martian*: But Venusian and I have spent much more time here than you, Human.
*Human*: However Venusian and I are of the same age.
*Venusian*: I have lived $300$ Earth years.
*Martian*: Venusian and I have been on Pluto for the last $13$ years.

It is known that Human and Martian together have lived for $104$ Earth years. Find their respective ages.

While solving this problem, I have a hint that the numbers are not necessarily expressed in base $10$ but I was unable to find any use of that statement. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Make no sense to me. In base $X$ the Human's age is at least $3X^2$ (sentences 5 &6) but from the last sentence ("It is known...") the Human's age is at most $X^2+4 .$ Together we have $3X^2\leq X^2+4,$ so $X^2\leq 2.$

Comment: @user254665 I have copied as it is from the book The IMO Compendium (Springer) . There is reportedly no mistake in the question.

Comment: @Rohan The very same book confirms your feeling in the foot note: "The numbers in the problem are not necessarily in base 10".

Comment: @Sil I forgot to mention that fact. I have corrected it. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: I have a suggestion: they can't all three be using the same number system. Otherwise, we'd have that Human and Venusian are of the same age, but by #1, #2,, and #4 both Martian and Venusian are much older than Human. So perhaps they're all using different bases. Though I don't know which base the 104 would be in.

Comment: I think the solutions of IMO problems are available on other sites

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We get a hint towards the different bases because otherwise the human would be three hundred years old, which is somewhat unrealistic.
So let $M$ and $V$ be the bases used by martians and venusians (whereas humans work in base ten) and let $t_M,t_H,t_V$ be the number of (presumably Earth) years each has spent on Pluto, and let $a_M,a_H,a_V$ be their ages in Earth years. We learn (all *my* numbers are in base ten, of course):

$$\begin{eqnarray}\tag1a_M &=& (M+2)t_M\\
\tag2a_H &=& 12t_H\\
\tag3a_V &=& (V+2)t_V\\
\tag5t_H&\ll&\begin{cases}t_M\\t_V\end{cases}\\
\tag6a_V &=&a_H\\
\tag7a_V &=& 3V^2\\
\tag8t_V&=&t_M=M+3
\end{eqnarray}$$
and of course $$\tag90<t_M\le a_M,\qquad0<t_H\le a_H,\qquad0<t_V\le a_V.$$
Also, the occurance of digits $2$ and $3$ tells us
$$ M>2,\qquad V>3.$$
From $(2)$, $(6)$, $(7)$, we have $12\mid 3V^2$, so $V$ is even, say $V=2W$. From $(3)$ and $(7)$, we have $V+2\mid 3V^2$, or $W+1\mid 6W^2$. As $\gcd(W+1,W)=1$, $W+1\mid 6$. Therefore $W\in\{0,1,2,5\}$, $V\in\{0,2,4,10\}$. 
From $(2)$, $(2)$, $(6)$ and $(5)$, we find $V<10$, hence together with $V>3$, we determined that 
$$V=4.$$
So $a_H=a_V=48$, $t_H=4$, and $t_V=t_M=8$. This makes $M=5$, so that $a_M=56$.

---

Incidentally, we indeed verify that $t_H+t_M=104$ - but we did not need that information to find the result.

Comment: Brilliant reasoning!

Comment: In the last line, I think you mean $a_H+a_m=104$. Great answer.